# Creating a modal dialog without jQuery

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am writing a plugin that depends on modal dialogs for screen space.

Right now I am using jQuery to create the dialogs, but I want a way that integrates better into the admin theme.

Obviously WP has to have some sort of native dialog system (it's used for uploads).   How do I access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WordPress admin area uses [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), which is still a jQuery plugin (jQuery is used all over the admin area). You need to enqueue the script and style (`add_thickbox()` does this for you), and then all links that have class `thickbox` will be converted. You need to add some URL parameters too, for example the image upload link looks like this: `media-upload.php?post_id=735&type=image&TB_iframe=1&width=640&height=285`. `post_id` and `type` are WordPress-specific, but `TB_iframe`, `width` and `height` are needed for Thickbox, and you should use them in your own links too.